# Does $\left\{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{2\pi n}{L} x}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ form a complete orthogonal basis in the interval $[-L/2,L/2]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, exponential-function, orthogonality

$\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi k x}$ and $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi k' x}$ are orthogonal in the following sense provided $k \ne k'$,

\begin{equation}
\langle \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi k x}, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi k' x}\rangle = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi k x} \, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi k' x} \, \mathrm{d}x = 0 \iff k \ne k'
\end{equation}

Therefore, $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi k x}$ forms a complete orthogonal basis over the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$

However, I'm interested in finding an orthogonal basis over the open interval $[-L/2,L/2]$, orthogonal such that

\begin{equation}
\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \overline{\phi_j(x)} \, \phi_k(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0 \iff j \ne k
\end{equation}

I found an orthogonal set by considering $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi k x}$, and removing terms not orthogonal to (to choose a starting point) $1$, yielding the basis

\begin{equation}
\left\{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \frac{2\pi n}{L}x}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}
\end{equation}

Is this a complete orthogonal basis?

It seem that starting from a complete basis over a large interval and culling only what isn't orthogonal to a starting basis function seems promising to forming another complete basis, but I'm not convinced by this argument very much. Especially since this choice of basis suggests that the function is periodic with period $L$. While it seems that any arbitrary function could be constructed from infinitely many terms in the basis, it seems to fall short in that (due to the interval being open) the value of any function at $x=-L/2$ is equal to that ay $x=L/2$ due to this periodicity, $f(-L/2) = f(L/2)$. Surely, if the basis was complete, these values could be made independent. Is it the case that the basis is complete except for one basis function. If so, what is this elusive function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you've already proved $\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}e^{i2\pi(n-m)x/L}dx=L\delta_{mn}$ for $m,\,n\in\Bbb Z$, so the $u_n(x):=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{i2\pi nx/L}$ form an orthonormal basis of the vector space they span. The hard part is how "diverse" a space of functions that is.

The way you've tried to write an arbitrary $f$ as a linear combination of these [sounds familiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-Schmidt_process), so let's say $\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}f_nu_n(x)$ is the attempted decomposition of $f(x)$ for some complex sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in\Bbb Z}$. (You might have only tried e.g. $n\in\Bbb N$, but you can probably adapt around that for the sake of this discussion.) But this raises a few issues:

- By definition, the space the $u_n$ *span* comprises only those $f$ for which we can choose all but finitely many of the $f_n$ to be zero, and such functions provably satisfy $f(x+L)\equiv f(x)$ (just induct on the number of non-zero $f_n$);
- In at least some cases where infinitely many $f_n$ are nonzero, the function $\tilde{f}(x):=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}f_nu_n(x)$ makes sense, e.g. as $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^Nf_nu_n(x)$;
- However, even when $\tilde{f}$ is an OK function it may not be the $f$ you aimed for. For example, even if I started with an $f$ that obtains $\tilde{f}=f$, you could construct a new function $g$, differing from $f$ at some but only countably points in $[-L/2,\,L/2]$. Then $\tilde{g}\equiv\tilde{f}\equiv f\not\equiv g$.

Don't let the periodicity of the $u_n$ make this mysterious. The aforementioned proof by induction can't be extended to the infinite-terms case. If you think about it, this isn't all that different from what happens with Taylor series:

- In the inner product $\langle h_1,\,h_2\rangle:=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{h_1(z)h_2^\ast(z)dz}{2\pi iz}$, the $z^n$ are orthonormal (with $n\in\Bbb Z$, but let's just look at $n\ge0$ so I don't need to talk about Laurent series);
- These monomials span the polynomials;
- Lots of non-polynomial Taylor series converge to a sensible function, but maybe not the one you expected.

Comment: Weierstrass's theorem gives a similar situation, although it is a little bit different because in Weierstrass's theorem the sequence of polynomials in general cannot be taken to be the partial sums of an infinite series.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really on the topic of the question, but the situation on the unbounded domain only intuitively works like you said. When written down carefully, the situation is much more subtle than that, and these subtleties have serious consequences in subjects like spectral theory.

Anyway, the situation in the bounded domain does work like you said. And yes, you have the counterintuitive situation that, given a $L^2$ function $f$ on $[-L/2,L/2]$, you can find a sequence of continuous *and periodic* functions $f_n$ which converge to $f$ in $L^2$ even if $f$ itself isn't periodic. (If you're not acquainted with the term $L^2$, replace the first instance with "continuous" and the second instance with "in the mean square sense").

The intuitive way that I interpret this is that $f$ on $[-L/2,L/2]$ is being understood as its periodic extension when we look at it from the point of view of Fourier series, so if it is actually not periodic then the periodic extension has a jump, near which the Fourier series misbehaves (but not so severely as to spoil the $L^2$ convergence). You can look up the Gibbs phenomenon to get some visualization of this.